# In Keyforge, does an attacked, exhausted creature deal damage to the attacking creature?

Tags: keyforge

The *Fight* rule says:

> Each of the two creatures deals an amount of damage equal to
>   its power (the value to the left of the card’s title) to the other creature.

However, if the attacked creature is exhausted, does it still strike back when attacked ?

Update after *Arcanist Lupus*'s answer: Creatures unexhaust at end of turn, but I used [Persistence Hunting](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/2-aoa/cards/328-persistence-hunting) to exhaust the enemy creature before I attacked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, they deal damage back (but they are probably not exhausted in the first place).

The rules you quote do not say anything about the exhausted status of a creature affecting how it fights. Therefore there is no effect.

That said, cards unexhaust at the *end* of your turn, not the start. Unless you have cards that allow you to exhaust your opponent's creatures, the creatures you are attacking will be unexhausted.